# What is wrong with my mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that checks whether or not a new entry is already existing in the table. if it exists, the insert will not happen. when I run it, there is an error

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AddPriority2;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE AddPriority2
(
    IN strName VARCHAR(100),
    OUT itExists INT
)
BEGIN
DECLARE 
SELECT COUNT(Id) INTO itExists
FROM priorities
WHERE Name = strName AND StatId = 1;

IF(itExists = 0) THEN
INSERT INTO priorities
(
    NAME,
    StatId
)
VALUES
(
    strName,
    1
);
END IF;
END
```

here is the error

```
Query: CREATE PROCEDURE AddPriority2 ( IN strName VARCHAR(100), OUT itExists INT ) BEGIN DECLARE SELECT COUNT(Id) INTO itExists FROM pr...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT COUNT(Id) INTO itExists
FROM priorities
WHERE Name = strName AND StatId =' at line 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You cannot declare a select statement - a declare has to be for a variable..(and I would not use an output parameter for that) 2) or you can use exists instead

```
if not exists (select 1 from priorities WHERE Name = strName AND StatId = 1) then
   insert...
end if;
```